# Disable access by file extension in Tomcat web.xml

Tags: tomcat, web.xml

Thanks to everyone in advance -

How would I go about disabling access via the browser by filetype?

For instance if I wanted to disable all access to .xml files how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no straightforward solution for this. At the end [of this post](http://www.java-forums.org/java-servlet/10701-restrict-users-entering-image-text-files-path-directly-browser.html), it is explained how you can use [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/JDBCRealm-howto.html) to create a security context around some files of your election. If a user tries to access a file that match your pattern (in your case *.xml), they would be redirected to a login or an error page.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted an answer to this myself, and wasn't satisfied with the JDBCRealm answer.

The default hidden folders "WEB-INF" and "META-INF" are hard coded in the Static Resource logic, so using the same mechanism seems prohibitively difficult.  You'd have to replace or modify some combination of [DefaultServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/catalina/funcspecs/fs-default.html), [StandardContext](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.html), and [StandardContextValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContextValve.html).  It's a mess.

But there are two simple ways I tried that accomplish the filtering you're after.

**Using a [Filter](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html)**

You can write a generic Servlet Filter to return 404 errors for any file matching some list.  You could setup that list as [Environment Entries](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Environment%20Entries) in context.xml, in a [properties file](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) on the classpath, stored in a database, or whatever your preference (even as hard-coded Strings, if you're some sort of masochist).

**Using a [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html)** *(Tomcat-specific)*

Tomcat Valves accomplish pretty much the same thing as Filters, but at a lower level.  They are not part of the [Servlet Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html), so your app wont be portable to other Servlet Containers.  Also, in my experiments with this, sending 404 responses do not go through the same channel as 404 responses sent normally in your application (e.g., if you setup custom 404 pages or handlers, they aren't used when a 404 returns from a Valve)

Answer (score 3):

There is even simpler way. You just redirect all requests with the specific extension to some empty servlet.

Like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Empty Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with Tomcat that does not accept a servlet-mapping without a corresponding servlet declaration.
I would recommend writting a simple ErrorServlet that sends 404 systematically such as:

```
package com.yourpackage;

public class ErrorServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public ErrorServlet(){
  }
  public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
  }
}
```

Then add the corresponding configuration in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
  <description>Servlet that displays a 404</description>
  <display-name>error</display-name>
  <servlet-class>com.yourpackage.ErrorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhmtl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's a solution which has worked for me. It leverages the security-constraint element in web.xml. You can place this within the web-app XML element of that file:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>block_xml</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

And this can be put in either the web.xml for a given webapp (WEB-INF/web.xml) or the conf/web.xml (to affect all apps).